# How to install directly from a package *.tgz file in NetBSD, OpenBSD, or FreeBSD

Tags: software-installation, package-management, freebsd, openbsd, netbsd

Is there any way to install software from the `*.tgz` file that is its package, in NetBSD?  Or indeed in operating systems with similar package managers such as OpenBSD or FreeBSD?

For example, I can install the nano editor on NetBSD using this command:

```
pkgin nano
```

(I could do the same with a similar `pkg install nano` command on FreeBSD.)

What if I download the package file directly from the operating system's package repository, which would be a URL like `http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/7.1/All/nano-2.8.7.tgz`?

Having obtained the package file from the repository by hand like this, is there any way to now install nano directly from it?  How do I do that?

Comment: The package systems of the various BSD systems may _look_ similar, but they are not the same.  The question should focus on a single BSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use `pkg_add`

from the manual:

> The pkg_add command is used to extract and upgrade packages that have
>        been previously created with the pkg_create(1) command.  Packages are
>        prepared collections of pre-built binaries, documentation, configura-
>        tions, installation instructions and/or other files.  pkg_add can recur-
>        sively install other packages that the current package depends on or
>        requires from both local disk and via FTP or HTTP.